# Python - Splitting a string by special characters and numbers

Tags: python, list, split, numbers, parentheses

I have a string that I want to split at every instance of an integer, unless an integer is directly followed by another integer. I then want to split that same string at "(" and ")".

```
myStr = ("H12(O1H2)2O2C1")
list1 = re.split('(\d+)', myStr)
print(list1)
list1 = re.split('(\W)', myStr)
print(list1)
```

I want the result to be ['H', '12', '(', 'O', '1', 'H', '2', ')', '2', 'O', '2', 'C', '1'].

After:

```
re.split('(\d+)', myStr)
```

I get:

```
['H', '12', '(O', '1', 'H', '2', ')', '2', 'O', '2', 'C', '1']
```

I now want to split up the open parenthesis and the "O" to make individual elements.
Trying to split up a list after it's already been split up the way I tried doesn't work.
Also, "myStr" eventually will be a user input, so I don't think that indexing through a known string (like myStr is in this example) would solve my issue.
Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to get what you want, change `(\d+)` to something like this `([\d]+|[\(\)])`

```
import re

myStr = ("H12(O1H2)2O2C12")
list1 = re.split('([\d]+|[\(\)])', myStr)
# print(list1)

noempty_list = list(filter(None, list1))
print(noempty_list)
```

Output:

```
['H', '12', '(', 'O', '1', 'H', '2', ')', '2', 'O', '2', 'C', '1']
```

You also have to match the `()` characters and without it will print `(O`, and since `re.split` returns a list with empty value(s), just remove it

With `([\d]+|[A-Z])` will work too but re.split will return more empty strings in the list